# liste max date with join

Tags: sql, firebird, greatest-n-per-group, firebird2.5

I have two tables container and LISTE_RECEPTD
I want to select the containers that have the value enstock = 1 and which exist in the LISTE_RECEPTD table with the last date of receipt max (rec_date) only.
noted that a number can exist several times in LISTE_RECEPTD.

**relation**

[image: relation]

**conteneur table**

[image: conteneur table]

**LISTE_RECEPTD**

[image: LISTE_RECEPTD]

I created a procedure
the problem that I have a false result.

```
    begin
FOR SELECT  conteneurs.numero FROM conteneurs
WHERE conteneurs.enstock=1
    INTO :NUMERO
DO
BEGIN
  FOR SELECT first 1  liste_receptd.recept_n ,max(liste_receptd.rec_date)    
 FROM liste_receptd
  where  liste_receptd.cont_numero=: NUMERO
    group BY liste_receptd.recept_n
  into :RECEPTION_N,:DATE_RECEPTION DO
              SUSPEND;
suspend;
end
```

END

**result**

[image: the result]

Thanks for your help

Comment: Your stored procedure is unnecessarily complex (and attempts to do what inner joins are for).

Answer (score 0):

I thing that the result is good, except duplicate rows. If you want only one row for select just remove one of `suspend` command.

```
  ......... 
    group BY liste_receptd.recept_n
  into :RECEPTION_N,:DATE_RECEPTION DO
              SUSPEND;
suspend; <-- REMOVE THIS
end
```

Or remove seccond 'FOR'
like this :

```
begin
FOR SELECT  conteneurs.numero FROM conteneurs
WHERE conteneurs.enstock=1
    INTO :NUMERO
DO
  BEGIN
   SELECT first 1  liste_receptd.recept_n ,max(liste_receptd.rec_date)    
   FROM liste_receptd
   where  liste_receptd.cont_numero=:NUMERO
   group BY liste_receptd.recept_n
   into :RECEPTION_N,:DATE_RECEPTION;
   SUSPEND;
  END
end
```

Comment: TOW BEGIN TOW END ,  "SQL error code = -104.
Unexpected end of command - line 21, column 1."

Comment: I just copy and edit a part of your code. Please see the last update. Not tested but this is the way.

Comment: yes its work with error "Arithmetic exception, numeric overflow, or string truncation
w" and new line ="null", thanks anyway ,I found the solution but not with a procedure

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you need to use a subquery to find the highest date per stock item, and then select the receival(s) that are associated with that date and stock item:

```
select s.*, r.*
from stock s
inner join (
    select max(rec_date) as max_rec_date, stockid
    from receival
    group by stockid
) latest
    on latest.stockid = s.id
inner join receival r
    on r.stockid = latest.stockid 
       and r.rec_date = latest.max_rec_date
```

If you only want the stock items that were received latest this can be simplified to:

```
select s.*, latest.*
from stock s
inner join (
    select max(rec_date) as max_rec_date, stockid
    from receival
    group by stockid
) latest
    on latest.stockid = s.id
```

Comment: LISTE_RECEPTD is view no id in this view

Comment: @kovarov my query is intended to demonstrate the solution, it is not the exact query to solve your problem. Instead of id, use `cont_numero`.

Comment: thank you a lot,its my served,I found the solution but not with a procedure

Answer (score 0):

I change the view "LISTE_RECEPTD"

### LISTE_RECEPTD

```
select 
    reception.recept_n,
    reception.rec_date,
    reception_d.cont_numero,
    conteneurs.enstock
from reception_d
   left outer join reception on (reception_d.recept_n = reception.recept_n)
   inner join conteneurs on (reception_d.cont_numero = conteneurs.numero)
```

Consequently I have this query that does the job

```
select distinct a.cont_numero NUMERO,a.rec_date  DATE_RECEPTION  ,
a.recept_n
from  liste_receptd a
where
(a.enstock=1 )
and (a.rec_date)=(select first 1 max(d.rec_date) last_date from  liste_receptd d where
a.cont_numero=d.cont_numero
group by d.rec_date
order by d.rec_date desc)

order by a.rec_date ,a.recept_n asc
;
```